# failing to use ffi-napi with webpack to ship to users

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, webpack, ffi

so am trying to use ffi-napi to import Go HTTP client that send valid TLS check it out [here](https://github.com/bogdanfinn/tls-client)

so my problem is that am always getting this error when running the exe

```
No native build was found for platform=win32 arch=x64 runtime=node abi=93 uv=1 libc=glibc node=16.16.0 webpack=true
    loaded from: C:\snapshot
```

i tried multiple solutions including adding

```
node : {
_dirname : true
}
```

and i cant require ffi-napi as external since it going to be at the user side app

this is my webpack file

```
const path = require('path');
const CopyPlugin = require("copy-webpack-plugin");
const ForkTsCheckerWebpackPlugin = require('fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin');

const HappyPack = require('happypack');

module.exports = {
  target: 'node',
  entry: './Main.ts',
  node: {
    __dirname: false
  },
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'Main.bundle.js',
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.ts'],
    modules: ['node_modules']
  },
  plugins: [
    new CopyPlugin({
      patterns: [{
        from: "./MainProd.ts",
        to: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')
      }],
    }),
    new ForkTsCheckerWebpackPlugin(),
    new HappyPack({
      id: 'ts',
      threads: 4,
      loaders: [{
        path: 'ts-loader',
        query: {
          happyPackMode: true
        }
      }]
    })
  ],
  mode: "production",
  node: {
    __dirname: false
  },
  module: {
    rules: [{
      test: /\.ts?$/,
      use: [{
          loader: 'ng-router-loader',
          options: {
            loader: 'async-import',
            genDir: 'compiled',
          }
        },
        {
          loader: 'happypack/loader?id=ts'
        }
      ]
    }]
  }
};
```

my node version : is 18.14.0
webpack version: 5.75.0
ffi-napi version: 4.0.3